# Pentaho running script from outside spoon directory

Tags: shell, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a shell script that should run the pentaho transforamtion job but it fails with the following error:

```
/data/data-integration/spoon.sh: 1: /data/data-integration/spoon.sh: ldconfig: not found
```

Here's the shell script which sits in:

```
/home/tureprw01/
```

and the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

/data/data-integration/./pan.sh -file=/data/reporting_scripts/op/PL_Op.ExtlDC.kjb >> /home/tureprw01/logs/PL_Op.ExtDC/$NOW.log
```

I'm completely green in terms of Java but need to make it work somehow

Comment: You should search for "ldconfig: not found" error for your distro.

Answer (score 0):

Using command line executions for Pan / Kitchen is simple, [This Documentation](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0L0/0Y0/070) should help you create the Batch/SH command and make it work.

Though i see you are using variable creation on the command line, personally i do not know if the Batch/SH variable is passed down correctly to the PDI parameters, you'd have to test that yourself, or use this variable definition within the PDI structure, not as a named parameter.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

## !/bin/sh

NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

cd /data/reporting_scripts/op/
/data/data-integration/spoon.sh -main org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan -initialDir /data/data-integration -file=/data/reporting_scripts/op/PL_Op.ExtlDC.kjb

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# use for jobs if you want to run transform change :
# "org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen" to "org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan" and insert ktr file

export PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=/root/app/jdk1.8.0_91
export JAVA_HOME=/root/app/jdk1.8.0_91

cd /{kjb path}/;

/{spoon path}/spoon.sh -main org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen -initialDir /{kjb path}//{kjb file}.kjb -repo=//{kjb path}/{resource file}.xml  -logfile=/{log file}.log -dir=/{kjb path}
```